# Multi-Monitor Configuration Software

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Is there any good multi-monitor software for Windows? Obviously, this is possible right through the OS, but I would like a little bit more control.

Because my three monitors are not all next to each other (two are, but one is wall-mounted), I would want the screen space to flow based on the actual monitor configuration. Right now, the wall monitor is on the right in windows (I have to move to the right to go what is actually up).

Is there any software that would let me configure based on the real positions?

Comment: Uh... how would the software know what the real positions *are*?

Comment: The user would manually configure. It wouldn't have to be to the exact pixel.

Comment: So then why aren't the OS facilities enough?

Comment: You can only configure the positions in a horizontal order, I would like more advanced manual control than that.

Comment: ... Really? I can place mine anywhere 360° around each other.

Comment: that's a new feature with windows 7 i think.

Answer (score 3):

UltraMon from http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/